# Is this plant a Lemon Lime Plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Is it Lemon Lime plant? and it is a kind of Dracaena?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pic from top to bottom (want to see the stem as well) please

Comment: @Bamboo Done. Sorry, I thought images of leaves would be enough :)

Comment: how long are the leaves, roughly - finding it hard to judge...

Comment: 11-14 inches @Bamboo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not 100% (there are so many Dracaenas) but I think, with leaves that length, it might be Dracaena deremensis - I've got one listed in my houseplant directory (UK version) as 'yellow stripe', but  can only find images of Dracaena deremensis Lemon and Lime on line, which appears to be the same as yellow stripe, or very similar anyway. Either that or its a variety of D. massangeana, but the fact its got crispy brown bits means its more likely D. deremensis, they easily get these patches, so yea, it may well be 'Lemon and Lime' as you call it, which would make it a D. deremensis variety.