# What is this Dracaena plant that looks like a lemon lime tree?

Tags: identification, houseplants, dracaena

[image]

My friend sent me this picture. He has only one and that is also not too clear. It looks like lemon lime plant. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is what this is. A very cool houseplant. Can also be grown outside in shade. Growing and caring is easy. Did you have any other questions on this? Some species of Dracaena are listed as toxic to pets, so caution is advised.

Comment: Are all Lemon Lime tree same as this? or they have different variety?  http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/26709/is-this-plant-a-lemon-lime-plant

Comment: There are definitely variants. It may not be common to see that in India, but in the West, nurseries develop breed variants and patent them to stay competitive. So, almost all common garden plants will be hybridized in some fashion or the other. Dracaena is very easy to adapt, so you will see many out there for every species and sub-species on an internet search.